# Splitting the first character of the words

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where i have to take the first letter of two words alone. Like I get the response from the WebService as `John Cooper` and i have to take `JC` from this.

I tried `sbstr(0,2)`, but this takes JO, is there any way we can form like above.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
'John Cooper'.split(' ').map(function (s) { return s.charAt(0); }).join('');
```

With [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
'John Cooper'.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
```

Comment: This regular expression assumes each word begins with a capital letter. Other answers have better regexs.

Comment: @Groady wrong. This regexp just replaces any lowercase letters with an empty string. The caret character `^` in this case means `not` (so the group in brackets matches anything but capital letters).

Answer (score 11):

To generalize the regex answer given by @katspaugh, this will work for all strings with any number of words, whether or not the first letter is capitalized.

```
'John Cooper workz'.replace(/\W*(\w)\w*/g, '$1').toUpperCase()
```

will result in `JCW`

obviously if you want to keep the case of the first letter each word, just remove the `toUpperCase()`

**SIDE NOTE**

with this approach, things like `John McCooper` will result in `JM` not `JMC`

Answer (score 3):

You can find some good javascript functions out-of-the-box on the web:

```
function getInitials(x)
{
        //(x is the name, e.g. John Cooper)

        //create a new variable 'seperateWords'
        //which uses the split function (by removing spaces)
        //to create an array of the words
        var seperateWords = x.split(" ");

        //also create a new empty variable called acronym
        //which will eventually store our acronym
        var acronym = "";

        //then run a for loop which runs once for every
        //element in the array 'seperateWords'.
        //The number of elements in this array are ascertained
        //using the 'seperateWords.length' variable
        for (var i = 0; i < seperateWords.length; i++){

            //Eacy letter is added to the acronym
            //by using the substr command to grab
            //the first letter of each word
            acronym = (acronym + seperateWords[i].substr(0,1));
        }

        //At the end, set the value of the field
        //to the (uppercase) acronym variable
        // you can store them in any var or any HTML element
        document.register.username2.value = toUpperCase(acronym);
}
```

The trick you missed from your try is to first `split` the name to separate First Name and Last Name.

[[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/k05nk/javascripthtml_get_initials_from_full_name/)]

Answer (score 3):

Well if i got you write so simply try the following

```
var words = 'John Cooper'.split(' ');
var shortcut = words[0][0] + words[1][0];
alert(shortcut);
```

//thats if you sure that is the name is in 2 words

Regards :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = "John Cooper";
var initials = "";
var wordArray = name.split(" ");
for(var i=0;i<wordArray.length;i++)
{
    initials += wordArray[i].substring(0,1);
}
document.write(initials);
```

Basically you split the string on the space and take the first character of each word.

Comment: [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is non-standard, better use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Comment: I did not know that - have changed it to `substring()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regular expression solution that supports accented letters like à and non-latin languages like Hebrew, and doesn't assume the name is Camel-Case:

```js
var name = 'ḟoo Ḃar';
var initials = name.replace(/\s*(\S)\S*/g, '$1').toUpperCase();
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = initials;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```